# How to write the <?xml> tag using scala.xml and Play Framework

Tags: xml, scala, playframework

Can anyone tell me how to write the "xml" tag to the output? As expected, loadString() method gets rid of it while loading.

```
object SitemapController extends Controller {

  def validDeals = Action { implicit request =>
    val xmlStr = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><msg>There's no xml tag</msg>" 
    Ok( scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmlStr) )
  } 
}
```

What I get beck from the controller is just

```
<msg>There's no xml tag</msg>
```

Answer (score 3):

`OK` is a `Status`, which uses a `Writable` typeclass to encode the content to bytes (`see Status.apply`). Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala#L70), the `Writable` for xml nodes just calls `toString`. Basically, instead of a document with an xml declaration, you are just getting a string representation of the root node.

To get the decl, you need to call `XML.write()` with a `java.io.Writer` and `xmlDecl = true`, as well as the other parameters. (I was able to supply a `null` for the DocType, instead of inventing one).

You could write to a StringWriter and then send that, but I think the most efficient way (especially if your document is large) would be to create an implicit `Writable` for `xml.Node` to override the builtin one.

Answer (score 1):

Play is very silly in handling XML. M.b. not many used it with?
Anyway, here is writeable that form proper xml document, also trims spaces.
Just import it in controller.

```
 object Implicits {    
    implicit def writeableOf_Node(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[NodeSeq] = {
      Logger.debug(s"Codec: $codec")
      Writeable{ xml => {
        val stringWriter = new StringWriter(1024)
        val node = scala.xml.Utility.trim(xml(0))
        scala.xml.XML.write(stringWriter, node, codec.charset, xmlDecl = true, null)
        val out = codec.encode(stringWriter.toString)
        stringWriter.close()
        out
      }}
    }
    }
```